# what is the difference of the meanings?

Tags: meaning, difference, ditransitive-verbs

Could you tell me the difference between the two below?

> I wish I had asked him his phone number.

> I wish I had listened to him his phone number.

Comment: In English, unlike in Japanese, "listen" and "ask" are different words with different meanings.  You should consult a dictionary to understand this difference.

Answer (score 1):

The second sentence is grammatically wrong, and should be:

> I wish I had heard his phone number.

Which has a different meaning than the first sentence. The second sentence means he tells you his phone number but the sentence does not mention you asking for it, while the first sentence does.

Answer (score 1):

The first one ("asked him") is correct.
The second one ("listened to him") is wrong.

"listened to him his phone number" is wrong because *ask* is a [**ditransitive** verb](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/ditransitive-verbs/), and *listen* is not.  *Ditransitive* means that the verb takes two objects.  The sentence works with *ask*, because the two objects are *him* and *his phone number*.  But you can't put two objects after *listen*.  If you really want to use *listen*, you have to rephrase the sentence so there is one object, like

> I wish I had listened to *him saying his phone number*